# ASP.NET - Rendering Gridview to HtmlTextWriter - XLS - Column Format

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, xls, htmltextwriter

I'm using the following code to render a gridview to an XLS file on an ASPX page:

```
Private Sub ExportGridviewToExcel()
    Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=ItemSizeExport.xls"
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GV_Item_Data.RenderControl(htw)
    Response.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

One of the columns is usually null, but sometimes contains a rather long integer such as 2342515123332222 .. it's a barcode type number... so no math ever has to be done on it.

Long story short, XLS makes this into a floating point and that's junk for the end-user.  (~23432**E**18)

**Is there some way for me to force this column in the XLS to be a string?**

I'm not willing to generate an XLS via any other method... my "fall back" would be to write a '#' character before each non-blank blank entry in that column hoping that that forces the column to be interpreted as text rather than a number. This is not an ideal solution though, unfortunately.

Comment: Im pretty sure thats just due to the formating of that cell, but not too sure how to go about changing that programatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a # character before each non-blank entry in that column, you could use an apostrophe. That will convert it to text. Another approach that might be possible is to attach a macro with column format info, but I'm not sure whether that's possible.

Comment: I tried the apostrophe, but for whatever reason Excel doesn't process it and simply displays it. However, in Excel, if I go in to edit one of those cells (with an apostrophe already prefixed), it "processes" it and it becomes a text cell as intended and removes the apostrophe.

Comment: There does not appear to be a clear answer on this one, so I'm accepting this one because it is informative.